# Weird behaviour of find -exec rm when using multiple name patterns

Tags: find, rm

I would expect the following command to delete all files with extension `.x` or `.z`, but instead it seems to only delete the first file listed:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/{a.x,b,c.z}
find foo -type f -name '*.x' -o -name '*.z'  # correctly lists a.x and c.z
find foo -type f -name '*.x' -o -name '*.z' -exec rm -f {} \+  
    # only deletes c.z
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: @steeldriver You are right, thanks for the link. I think I will just start using xargs instead of exec, so many hidden tricks..

Comment: `xargs` will bite unless you're careful. Use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` for example. And for deleting, `find ... -delete` may be better.